# How to get postgres command 'nth_value' equivalent in pyspark Hive SQL?

Tags: python, postgresql, apache-spark, pyspark, window-functions

I was solving this example :
https://www.windowfunctions.com/questions/grouping/5
Here, they use Oracle or postgres command `nth_value` to get the answer, but this is not implemented in Hive SQL which is used by pyspark and I was wondering how to obtain the same result in pyspark.

## postgres sql code

- All weights greater than 4th are assigned 4th smallest weight
- First three lightest weights are assigned value 99.9

```sql
select name, weight, 
coalesce(nth_value(weight, 4) over (order by weight), 99.9) as imagined_weight
from cats 
order by weight
```

## Question: How to get following result using pyspark?

```
name    weight  imagined_weight
Tigger  3.8 99.9
Molly   4.2 99.9
Ashes   4.5 99.9
Charlie 4.8 4.8
Smudge  4.9 4.8
Felix   5.0 4.8
Puss    5.1 4.8
Millie  5.4 4.8
Alfie   5.5 4.8
Misty   5.7 4.8
Oscar   6.1 4.8
Smokey  6.1 4.8
```

## Data

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

import pyspark
from pyspark.sql.types import *
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
from pyspark.sql.window import Window
from pyspark import SparkConf, SparkContext, SQLContext
spark = pyspark.sql.SparkSession.builder.appName('app').getOrCreate()
sc = spark.sparkContext
sqlContext = SQLContext(sc)
sqc = sqlContext
# spark_df = sqlContext.createDataFrame(pandas_df)

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'name': [
        'Molly', 'Ashes', 'Felix', 'Smudge', 'Tigger', 'Alfie', 'Oscar',
        'Millie', 'Misty', 'Puss', 'Smokey', 'Charlie'
    ],
    'breed': [
        'Persian', 'Persian', 'Persian', 'British Shorthair',
        'British Shorthair', 'Siamese', 'Siamese', 'Maine Coon', 'Maine Coon',
        'Maine Coon', 'Maine Coon', 'British Shorthair'
    ],
    'weight': [4.2, 4.5, 5.0, 4.9, 3.8, 5.5, 6.1, 5.4, 5.7, 5.1, 6.1, 4.8],
    'color': [
        'Black', 'Black', 'Tortoiseshell', 'Black', 'Tortoiseshell', 'Brown',
        'Black', 'Tortoiseshell', 'Brown', 'Tortoiseshell', 'Brown', 'Black'
    ],
    'age': [1, 5, 2, 4, 2, 5, 1, 5, 2, 2, 4, 4]
})

schema = StructType([
    StructField('name', StringType(), True),
    StructField('breed', StringType(), True),
    StructField('weight', DoubleType(), True),
    StructField('color', StringType(), True),
    StructField('age', IntegerType(), True),
])

sdf = sqlContext.createDataFrame(df, schema)
sdf.createOrReplaceTempView("cats")

spark.sql('select * from cats limit 2').show()
```

## My attempt so far

```py
# My attempt
q = """
select weight from (
  select name,weight, 
         ROW_NUMBER() over (ORDER BY weight) as row_no
  from cats group by weight,name
  ) res 
where res.row_no = 4
"""
spark.sql(q).show()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An alternative option is `row_number()` and a conditional window function:

```
select
    name,
    weight,
    coalesce(
        max(case when rn = 4 then weight end) over(order by rn),
        99.9
    ) imagined_weight
from (select c.*, row_number() over(order by weight) rn from cats c) c
```