# How to get postgres command 'nth_value' equivalent in pyspark Hive SQL for partition over?

Tags: python, sql, postgresql, pyspark, hive

I was solving this example :
https://www.windowfunctions.com/questions/grouping/6
Here, they use Oracle or postgres command `nth_value` to get the answer, but this is not implemented in Hive SQL which is used by pyspark and I was wondering how to obtain the same result in pyspark.

## postgres sql code

```sql
select distinct(breed),
       nth_value(weight, 2) over ( partition by breed order by weight
                                   RANGE BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING
                                   AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING
                                   ) as imagined_weight
from cats 
order by breed
```

## Question: How to get following result using pyspark?

```
breed   imagined_weight
British Shorthair   4.8
Maine Coon  5.4
Persian 4.5
Siamese 6.1
```

## Data

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

import pyspark
from pyspark.sql.types import *
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
from pyspark.sql.window import Window
from pyspark import SparkConf, SparkContext, SQLContext
spark = pyspark.sql.SparkSession.builder.appName('app').getOrCreate()
sc = spark.sparkContext
sqlContext = SQLContext(sc)
sqc = sqlContext
# spark_df = sqlContext.createDataFrame(pandas_df)

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'name': [
        'Molly', 'Ashes', 'Felix', 'Smudge', 'Tigger', 'Alfie', 'Oscar',
        'Millie', 'Misty', 'Puss', 'Smokey', 'Charlie'
    ],
    'breed': [
        'Persian', 'Persian', 'Persian', 'British Shorthair',
        'British Shorthair', 'Siamese', 'Siamese', 'Maine Coon', 'Maine Coon',
        'Maine Coon', 'Maine Coon', 'British Shorthair'
    ],
    'weight': [4.2, 4.5, 5.0, 4.9, 3.8, 5.5, 6.1, 5.4, 5.7, 5.1, 6.1, 4.8],
    'color': [
        'Black', 'Black', 'Tortoiseshell', 'Black', 'Tortoiseshell', 'Brown',
        'Black', 'Tortoiseshell', 'Brown', 'Tortoiseshell', 'Brown', 'Black'
    ],
    'age': [1, 5, 2, 4, 2, 5, 1, 5, 2, 2, 4, 4]
})

schema = StructType([
    StructField('name', StringType(), True),
    StructField('breed', StringType(), True),
    StructField('weight', DoubleType(), True),
    StructField('color', StringType(), True),
    StructField('age', IntegerType(), True),
])

sdf = sqlContext.createDataFrame(df, schema)
sdf.createOrReplaceTempView("cats")

spark.sql('select * from cats limit 2').show()
```

## My attempt so far

```py
# My attempt
q = """
select
    distinct(breed),
    ( max(case when rn = 2 then weight end)
      over(partition by breed order by weight
                                   RANGE BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING
                                   AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING)
    ) imagined_weight
from (
  select 
    c.*,
    row_number() over(order by weight) rn
    from cats c
    ) c
"""
spark.sql(q).show()
```

## References

- [How to get postgres command 'nth_value' equivalent in pyspark Hive SQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63023375/how-to-get-postgres-command-nth-value-equivalent-in-pyspark-hive-sql/63023607#63023607)

Comment: And what is the issue with your code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want the second lowest weight per breed:

```
select breed,
       max(case when seqnum = 2 then weight end) as imagined_weight
from (select  c.*, row_number() over (partition by breed order by weight) as seqnum
      from cats c
     ) c
group by breed;
```